# render view in yii console application

Tags: rendering, yii

I have an email template in a view and I want to write a process that is ConsoleApplication that prepares emails to be send. Becouse it is ConsoleApplication I have no access to controller. Is it any way to render a view?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is what I use:

```
private function render($template, array $data = array()){
    $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.views.email').'/'.$template.'.php';
    if(!file_exists($path)) throw new Exception('Template '.$path.' does not exist.');
    return $this->renderFile($path, $data, true);
}
```

It takes email template from **views/email**.

Comment: is there any good way to render from model? or is there any link to CConsoleCommand currently launched?

Comment: Add this method to your console command. You can pass an array with $this and your model to $data parameter.

Comment: downvote, no usage example provided, what a mess it is  just to paste into command

Comment: Any way to use a layout file from the console?

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails (as in my case):

```
<?php


    /**
    * Renders a view file & returns result.
    * @param string $_viewFile_ view file path
    * @param array $_data_ optional data to be extracted as local view variables
    * @param boolean $_return_ whether to return the rendering result instead of displaying it
    * @return mixed the rendering result if required. Null otherwise.
         */
public function myRenderPartial($_viewFile_,$_data_=null,$_return_=true) {

    if(is_array($_data_))
        extract($_data_,EXTR_PREFIX_SAME,'data');
    else
        $data=$_data_;

    if($_return_)
    {
        ob_start();
        ob_implicit_flush(false);
        require(YiiBase::getPathOfAlias("application.views").$_viewFile_.'.php');
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    else
    {
        require($_viewFile_);
    }
}   

?>
```